# Sublime says Array.includes() is not a javascript function

Tags: javascript, sublimetext

I recently moved to a proper code editor, Sublimetext 3. Found the instructions to get a javascript build system installed, which is downright marvelous, but after a while, I got a strange type error:

```
somefile.js:290
if (_ALPHABET.includes(chr))
              ^

TypeError: _ALPHABET.includes is not a function
```

Even double checked the js reference guide and I swear; includes() is a genuine array function! I can also run the exact same code in Firebug without an error. So is the problem with my build system?

I discovered it here -> [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/370e35/how-to-run-or-debug-javascript-in-sublime-text/)

But it was only one of several examples. Does anybody recognize the issue?

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` is a pending ES7 feature. It's not part of any currently accepted spec. So that may be why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @squint I see... did not think to check for that. Ohh well, I'm sure there is another way or I'll just loop it myself. Thank you.